# How can I get around this issue with interfaces?

Tags: c#, interface

I am using Entity Framework and that's where my issue is, but it is probably not relevant as I think this is a generic C# question.

I have a `MyContext` class which has many `DbSet<T>` properties.

In order to unit test it, I edited MyContext so these are `IDbSet<T>` instead and mock it all up. `IDbSet<T>` is part of Entity Framework and DbSet implements it so the two are almost identical.

Everything works great like this, because I can do to `IDbSet<T>` everything I could do to `DbSet<T>`

Everything except for one thing - `DbSet` has a method called `SqlQuery(..)` that I also want to be able to call from my `IDbSet`.

Since I can't alter `DbSet` or `IDbSet`, this leaves me with a conundrum. I can't get my head around exactly how I can make it so my `IDbSet` is able to have a `SearchQuery(..)` method added to it in some logical fashion.

Does that make sense? I'm quite confused so I may have overlooked something really simple, such as copy & pasting `IDbSet` and renaming it and adding `SearchQuery()`. Any ideas?

Comment: How about a title which actually summarizes your question?

Comment: Can you think of one? I can't :S I tried "When mocking a class by changing a property to use an interface of itself, how can I retain access to a method that didn't belong to the original interface when I don't have access to the interface or the class as they belong to an external library?" but the maximum length is 150 characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

I believe I got what you're looking for - wrappers everywhere, possibly more trouble than it's worth, but worth a look:

```
// An interface which implements IDbSet<T> and adds on the method you want
public interface IExtendedDbSet<T> : IDbSet<T>
    where T : class
{
    DbSqlQuery<T> SqlQuery(string sql, object[] parameters);
}

// Implement this interface by wrapping around a regular DbSet<T>.
// You implement all the methods and properties by just wrapping the DbSet<T>
// calls
public class ExtendedDbSet<T> : IExtendedDbSet<T>
    where T : class
{
    private readonly DbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public ExtendedDbSet(DbSet<T> dbSet) { _dbSet = dbSet; }

    DbSqlQuery<T> IExtendedDbSet<T>.SqlQuery(string sql, object[] parameters)
    {
        return _dbSet.SqlQuery(sql, parameters);
    }

    T IDbSet<T>.Add(T entity) { return _dbSet.Add(entity); }
    T IDbSet<T>.Attach(T entity) { return _dbSet.Attach(entity); }
    TDerivedEntity IDbSet<T>.Create<TDerivedEntity>() { return _dbSet.Create<TDerivedEntity>(); }
    T IDbSet<T>.Create() { return _dbSet.Create(); }
    T IDbSet<T>.Find(params object[] keyValues) { return _dbSet.Find(keyValues); }
    ObservableCollection<T> IDbSet<T>.Local { get { return _dbSet.Local; } }
    T IDbSet<T>.Remove(T entity) { return _dbSet.Remove(entity); }
    IEnumerator<T> IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator() { return ((IEnumerable<T>)_dbSet).GetEnumerator(); }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return ((IEnumerable)_dbSet).GetEnumerator(); }
    Type IQueryable.ElementType { get { return ((IQueryable)_dbSet).ElementType; } }
    Expression IQueryable.Expression { get { return ((IQueryable)_dbSet).Expression; } }
    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider { get { return ((IQueryable)_dbSet).Provider; } }
}

// A regular context class, no special interfaces to implement or
// custom properties or anything.
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

// An interface representing your context, which exposes extended DbSet<T>
// for your sets. Also define SaveChanges() and whatever else you may need
// to call on your context object.
public interface IMyContext
    : IDisposable
{
    IExtendedDbSet<Car> Cars { get; }
    int SaveChanges();
}

// A wrapper around your regular context. For each set, return an
// ExtendedDbSet<T> wrapper.
public class MyContextWrapper : IMyContext
{
    private readonly MyContext _myContext;

    public MyContextWrapper(MyContext myContext) { _myContext = myContext; }

    IExtendedDbSet<Car> IMyContext.Cars
    {
        get { return new ExtendedDbSet<Car>(_myContext.Cars); }
    }

    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _myContext.Dispose();
    }

    int IMyContext.SaveChanges()
    {
        return _myContext.SaveChanges();
    }
}

// Define your context variable as IMyContext, and create it
// by creating a wrapper around a regular context. The properties
// of the interface will be extended wrappers around your sets.
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (IMyContext context = new MyContextWrapper(new MyContext()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(context.Cars.SqlQuery("select 1", new object[0]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I first started using EF, there was no `IDbSet`, so this is what I did.

Comment: Instead of storing a reference to `DbSet<T>` perhaps I could just make it implement `IDbSet<T>, IExtendedDbSet<T>` ?

Comment: In this example, `IExtendedDbSet<T>` already implements `IDbSet<T>`, so it picks up all of the other properties/methods from the base interface. You still need a regular `DbSet<T>` instance, because that's what Entity Framework gives you. You could try inheriting from `DbSet<T>` instead of composition, but you may not be able to get all the private stuff from one to the other while converting. With composition, since everything's a wrapper, all the private implementation is still there for you.

Comment: Seems you can't extend `DbSet<T>` because it has no constructor. I was hoping for a nicer way. I'm going to try and implement this.

Comment: Okay, I've tried to implement this, but I get an error when I run my solution as the value of the properties on the context are all set to null, and the constructor never fires. Could I be missing something?

Comment: I edited my answer regarding the context class - not sure if this is the problem, but if so, another wrapper might be the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, I'll try that - although when I changaed `DbSet` to `IDbSet` it worked, and `IExtendedDbSet` implements that, so I wouldn't have thought it'd go wrong.

Comment: I'm just wondering, wouldn't EF need to use the setter for the property as well as the getter, to first define it as an empty DbSet? How would I implement that, as I'm using the custom `IExtendedDbSet` rather than `IDbSet`

Comment: Sadly it didn't work, the properties were all still null despite me implementing the interface and exposing an `IDbSet<Car> IMycontext.Cars`

Comment: See the edit. I've got a working codebase - not sure if it delivers everything you need, but everything is wrapped around normal EF classes, so you shouldn't have any framework problems.

Comment: Thanks for the code, as a temporary? fix I used IDbSet and added a partial class that had the `SqlQuery` function in and an interface. I will investigate your solution as a better long term strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it may not be the most elegant solution, but you could simply write an extension method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> SearchQuery(this IDbSet<T> set, string query)
{
    var dbSet = set as DbSet<T>;
    if (dbSet != null)
    {
        return dbSet.SqlQuery(query);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't this make all tests that use SearchQuery fail?

Comment: I can probably use reflection or similar instead of only casting to `DbSet`. Unless there is a better solution. Maybe I can extend `DbSet` and add an interface onto it.